# Simple Async Task Button not outputting boolean value when code behind it exists

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, boolean

I am trying to eventually process the readMessage string into a 2-D Array. I do realize that 'a' is not being incremented right now. Regardless, bool is not being outputted as true when I press the button. The toast still says false.

**UPDATE:** My toast outputs the proper bool value when the other code before it does not exist, I'm talking about the filling up of the 2-D array. When that is there, nothing happens. Its been a minute and I still haven't seen the toast. This also with only one value!

```
public Button seizureResult;
public double [][]stored = new double[8000][1];
public static HjorthClass finalValue;
public int a=0;
public String transfer;
public boolean bool;


    seizureResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Complete();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    });

private class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        if(transfer == null)
        {
            transfer = "0";
        }
        double[] convert = new double[1];
        for(int z=0; z <1;z++)
            {
        convert[z]= Double.parseDouble(transfer);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<1;j++)
        {
        stored[a][j]= convert[j];
        }
        bool = true;
        return bool;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   

}


public void Complete()
{
    ProcessData task = new ProcessData();
    task.execute(transfer);
}


private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf,0,msg.arg1);
            transfer = readMessage;
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Voltage: "+ transfer);
            break;
```

Comment: the reason of false is the asyncTask being run as soon as you click button and it's not yet completed and you toast the value and it shows the default that is false yet!

Comment: So this code is running properly, but I am not viewing it correctly? Should my toast be in doInBackground method?

Comment: yes your code seems fine, what you need to do is use onPostExecute to show your toast after getting boolean from doInBackground()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTask class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

please read this [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [THIS](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)  to get idea "How AsyncTask works"

try this code

```
private class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

 @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    //your code here
    boolean bool = true;
return bool;
}

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Comment: You should get an error for Long result, this should be Boolean. since the <String, Void, Boolean>. I get the error remove @Override annotation

Answer (score 2):

Override the `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` and then execute the `Toast` message from `onPostExecute()` method instead from `onClick()` method as follows...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(boolean bool) {
    super.onPostExecute(bool);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I get two errors, data not initialized, and remove @Override annotation

Answer (score 0):

override onPostExecute method of Async Task which will be called as soon the task is completed and show your toast there

Comment: I get the error "Remove Override statement": My code is:
 @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean... result)
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

Comment: whats your android version

Comment: I updated the code up top - Android version is 4.0.4

Comment: take out the three dots after Boolean result parameters

Comment: well that got rid of the error, but its been like 30 seconds and it still hasn't given a toast message

Comment: where you calling public void Complete()
{
    ProcessData task = new ProcessData();
    task.execute(transfer);
}

Comment: you have to make a call to start your task, just call it oncreate event of your activity to execute the task

Comment: what do you mean? Aren't I calling it with the onclick listener?

Comment: you are but are you sure it is being called successfully, just display another toast in oncomplete method to see if this method is called

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    try
    {
    if(transfer == null)
    {
        transfer = "0";
    }
    double[] convert = new double[1];
    for(int z=0; z <1;z++)
    {
    convert[z]= Double.parseDouble(transfer);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<1;j++)
    {
    stored[a][j]= convert[j];
    }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
    }
    finalValue = new HjorthClass(stored);
    bool = finalValue.returnSum();
    bool = true;
```

//Use runOnUiThread(){
/*here you can show toast with bool value and yes there are many ways to do that but you want to do anything related to UI from background Thread you must Ui Thread , in you click functionality you are trying to show toast before anything val is assigned to bool(because asynctask is still running*/
}

```
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While user1799320's is correct, (see the comments) his answer is not entirely correct. The reason for the toast or the bool value not being updated to true was because of the code doInBackground before bool was set to true. Commenting this code out makes the code function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check bellow code.

public void Complete()

{

ProcessData task = new ProcessData();

```
task.execute(transfer);

boolean bl=task.get();
```

}

Comment: boolean bl=task.get();